# Normal Vector to a Sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having kind of a problem on calculating the normal vector to a sphere using a parameterization. Consider a unit-radius sphere centered at the origin.

One can parameterize it using the following:
$$P(\phi, \theta)=(\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),\,\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\,\cos(\phi)) $$

My Vector Calculus book says that the Vector Product between the two partial derivates of the parameterized surface gives a Normal Vector to the surface.

I found that
$$\frac {\partial P(\phi, \theta)}{\partial \phi} \times \frac {\partial P(\phi, \theta)}{\partial \theta} = (\sin^2(\phi)\cos(\theta))\hat i + (\sin^2(\phi)\sin(\theta))\hat j + (\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi))\hat k$$

Which, as one can easily verify, yields $(0, 0,0)$ for $(\phi,\theta) = (0,0)$ which means that the sphere is not regular at the point $(0,0,1)$. That is obviously wrong, so I would like to know where is my mistake.

Comment: As a level surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ is a sphere. The normal vector is given by $<2x,2y,2z>$ which is clearly non-trivial provided $R \neq 0$. As mentioned, the trouble you find is due to the coordinates chosen, it's not a genuine defect of the space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a sphere, the surface normal is exactly your $P(\phi,\theta)$, since the normal is just the vector from the origin. Your vector $\vec N$ is indeed normal to the surface, but it's not normalized: 
$$|\vec N| = |\sin \phi \cdot \vec P| \neq1$$
The correct definition of the [surface normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) , coupled with the limit $\theta \to 0$ should give you the correct result:
$$\vec N=\frac{\vec a \times \vec b}{\sqrt{|\vec a|^2|\vec b|^2-|\vec a\cdot\vec b|^2}}$$
Where:
$$\vec a = \vec P_\phi, \ \ \vec b =\vec P_\theta$$

Comment: But why does the vector product give the wrong result? Shouldn't it work for every surface?

Comment: @Thiago - fixed (I hope).

Comment: So I can only talk about surface regularity when evaluating the normalized normal vector?

Comment: No, it's just that the Jacobian of the parameterization you chose is singular at $\theta=n\pi$, so that your formula doesn't work there. The surface Normal obviously exists as you pointed out yourself.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical example of singular point(s) arising from the parametrization, they are called the *artificial singularities*.

For a parametrized surface: $S: \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}(u,v)$, like you said:
$$
\mathrm{If } \;\; \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \neq 0,
$$
then it indeed is a normal vector (un-normalized) to the surface $S$. Now:
$$
\frac {\partial P(\phi, \theta)}{\partial \phi} \times \frac {\partial P(\phi, \theta)}{\partial \theta} = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i}& \mathbf{j} &\mathbf{k}
\\
\cos\phi \cos\theta & \cos\phi \sin\theta & -\sin\phi
\\
-\sin\phi \sin\theta & \sin\phi \cos\theta & 0 \end{vmatrix},
$$
notice the cross product is 0 for $\phi = 0,\pi$, this happens due to the choice of parametrization. For example, if you choose the angle between $y$-axis as the polar angle, then this singular point will be gone (other arises though), and this gives you a heuristics of one of the reasons why we wanna cut a manifold into pieces and establish a local coordinate system...