# Sphere of normals

Tags: differential-geometry, general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In my situation, I've constructed a quotient space $M/\sim$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that must be a $2$-manifold. If $M/ \sim$ is a sphere then I know that its normal spaces must vary at least 90 degrees. That is $M / \sim$ must exhibit a full sphere of normal spaces. Suppose instead that $M / \sim$ has a handle. Can I always choose a loop around the handle that also implies that the normals of $M / \sim$  must vary by at least 90 degrees?

Comment: This is not a research question.  I've voted to migrate it.

Comment: Old question but this may help - 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423282/normal-vector-to-a-sphere